# How to place Text and an Image next to each other in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, text

I want the text and the image to be next to each other but I want the image to be on the far left of the screen and I want the text to be on the far right of the screen. This is what I currently have....

```
<body>
<img src="website_art.png" height= "75" width= "235"/>
<h3><font face="Verdana">The Art of Gaming</font></h3>
</body>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: CSS: `float: left;` and `float: right`?

Comment: The `<font>` tag has been removed as of HTML5. Please remove it and replace it with the equivalent CSS ;)

Comment: You can use css to place them in a div and use the appropriate float:right or left to have them on their respective sides.  div width can be set to allow you to have "far left" and "far right" how you want.

Answer (score 44):

```
img {
    float:left;
}
h3 {
    float:right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WW4N6/)**

Note that you will probably want to use the style `clear:both` on whatever elements comes after the code you provided so that it doesn't slide up directly beneath the floated elements.

Comment: Only problem is that a parent div will size and that's a problem if you're using a background color, etc

Comment: @User What does "a parent div will size" mean?

Answer (score 9):

You want to use [css float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) for this, you can put it directly in your code.

```
<body>
<img src="website_art.png" height= "75" width="235" style="float:left;"/>
<h3 style="float:right;">The Art of Gaming</h3>
</body>
```

But I would really suggest learning the basics of css and splitting all your styling out to a separate style sheet, and use classes. It will help you in the future. A good place to start is [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) or, perhaps later down the path, [Mozzila Dev. Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <img src="website_art.png" class="myImage"/>
  <h3 class="heading">The Art of Gaming</h3>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myImage {
  float: left;
  height: 75px;
  width: 235px;
  font-family: Veranda;
}
.heading {
  float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertical-align and floating.

In most cases you want to vertical-align: middle, the image.

Here is a test: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align

vertical-align: baseline|length|sub|super|top|text-top|middle|bottom|text-bottom|initial|inherit;

For middle, the definition is: The element is placed in the middle of the parent element.

So you might want to apply that to all elements within the element.

Comment: I don't think `vertical-align` and `float` work together.