# How to align div to img?

Tags: html, css

I want to have my html element like this :

[image: Wireframe]

But I don't know how to do it.

My html :

```
<header>
    <img src="res/LogoMPS.png">
    <h1>Consultation Proface</h1>
    <a id="retourAccueil" href="/MPS">Accueil MPS</a>
</header>
```

and my actual CSS :

```
img {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 8%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font: 40px Arial;
    color: #0448af;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#retourAccueil {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You mean that putting the string `Logo MPS` to the image at the top position?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to place Text and an Image next to each other in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219757/how-to-place-text-and-an-image-next-to-each-other-in-html)

Comment: You gave the image an width of 80% meaning there is only 20% for the slogan. I thing you have to give them both 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could vertically align both the texts using `flexbox` and `align-items: center;` if you add an inner `div` wrapper in the `header`

```css
header {
   padding: 30px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   font-family: Arial;
}

header div { margin-left: 20px }
header h1  { margin: 0 0 10px; }
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/150/100">
    <div>
      <h1>Consultation Proface</h1>
      <a id="retourAccueil" href="/MPS">Accueil MPS</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You don't need `flexbox` to achieve this.

Comment: That doesn't mean you might not use it, it's an approach like another

Comment: I understand, but this solution isn't very well supported with older browsers. So if you can do it without flexbox, you should try to.

Comment: Flexbox is supported since IE11. So it depends on the support you have to ensure.

Comment: I know, I just believe for something trivial like this, flexbox isn't really needed but it works so hey, what does it matter?

Comment: If you like to use another approach, it's fine. If we propose different solutions is fine as well. There's nothing wrong in using different - working - solutions. Let the users (not only the OP) decide what approach fits better for their problems.

Comment: I never said there was anything **wrong** with your post, I'm glad there are people choosing their own ways. It gives the OP more choice between what they think would fit in their project better. I just wanted to let you know that it can be done without flexbox because a lot of developers tend to rely on it heavily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204215/discussion-between-fcalderan-and-halden-collier).

Comment: Question (screenshgot) was to center h1 and put the anchor below it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `div` around your text, then we apply the styles to that. 
You should vertical align both you `img` and new `div`. Now this alone works fine, but the text might seem ever so slightly offset, you can fix this by removing the top `margin` on your `h1` tag.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

header img, header div { vertical-align: middle; }

header div {
  padding-left: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" />
  <div>
    <h1>Consultation Proface</h1>
    <a href="#">Accueil MPS</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in this case it's quite simple: apply the vertical align to the image. Since it's all in one line, it's really the image you want aligned, not the text.

```css
.test{
  display: flex;
   align-items:center;
  }
img {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 8%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
    font: 40px Arial;
    color: #0448af;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#retourAccueil {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="test">
<img src="res/LogoMPS.png">
    <h1>Consultation Proface</h1>
    <a id="retourAccueil" href="/MPS">Accueil MPS</a>
    </div>
    
</header>
```

Comment: You can just use `vertical-align` rather than `flexbox`

Comment: If we want each elements' contents to be vertically centered, we can use flexbox and align-items to make that happen.Flexbox was always promised to be the savior of web layout but appears to have flamed out a bit in favor of CSS grid.

Comment: I would still pick `flexbox` over `CSS grid` anyday, however I would choose vanilla CSS over `flexbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex for the layout. All comments in the css.

```
<header>
  <img src="res/LogoMPS.png">
  <div>
    <h1>Consultation Proface</h1>
    <a id="retourAccueil" href="/MPS">Accueil MPS</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

with this css

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* border & padding within width/height */
}
html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* to use rem */
}
body {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: col wrap; /* vertical center */
  align-items: center; /* vertical center */
}
header div {
  padding-left: 10px; /* space between img and text */
}
header img {
  flex: 0 0 8%;
  width: 8%;
  min-width: 80px; /* set min width for img */
  height: auto; /* responsive */
  border: 0; /* remove default border */
}
header h1 {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
  padding-top: 0.75rem; /* push h1 down, h1 stays centered with <a> below it */
  font-size: 1.25rem; /* not the default size */
  font-weight: 500; /* not the default font weight */
}
header a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<header>
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-graphic-elegant-font-sample-260nw-302634320.jpg">
    <h3>Consultation Proface</h3>
    <a id="retourAccueil" href="/MPS">Accueil MPS</a>
</header>


    img {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 8%;
    float:left;
}

h3 {

}

#retourAccueil {

   display:inline-block;
}
```