# New to html How do i make image side by side to the text

Tags: html, css

As said in title just want to make my image appear side by side to the text in the "title" element

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
 .logo {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px white;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
  
  }

.main{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
   

}
.element{
    background-color:#3c3B37;
    }
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cccccc, white);
  
  
  
}
.title p {
  margin: 6px;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>


 <div class="main">
 <div class="element">
 <img class="logo" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="snow" />
 <div class="title"> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop pub
 </p></div>

 </div>
 <div class="element">
 <img class="logo" src="img_forest.jpg" alt="forest" />
 <div class="title"> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop pub
 </p></div>
 </div>
 <div class="element">
 <img class="logo" src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="mountains" />
 <div class="title"> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
2
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop pub
 </p></div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

here's the output I'm getting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONLA6.png)

tried using display in-block to make the images in the "logo" element appear in rows side by side to the text in element "title" but instead seperated them into two different inline-blocks

Comment: You need to learn about the `float` attribute.  Make the image `float: left` and your text will line up next to it.  Use `clear: both` when you want to start a new set.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate. Have you checked out these posts?
[How to place Text and an Image next to each other in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17219757/5181837)
[How to display items side-by-side without using tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438910/how-to-display-items-side-by-side-without-using-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just modified below code

```
.element{
 display:flex;         // Just added display:flex
 background-color:#3c3B37;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
 .logo {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px white;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
  
  }

.main{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
   

}
.element{
    display:flex;
    background-color:#3c3B37;
    }
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #cccccc, white);
  
  
  
}
.title p {
  margin: 6px;
}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>


 <div class="main">
 <div class="element">
 <img class="logo" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="snow" />
 <div class="title"> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop pub
 </p></div>

 </div>
 <div class="element">
 <img class="logo" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="forest" />
 <div class="title"> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop pub
 </p></div>
 </div>
 <div class="element">
 <img class="logo" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="mountains" />
 <div class="title"> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply
dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
2
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the
1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop pub
 </p></div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to use float, that's what it was built for!

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https:\\placeholder.com\50">
<p>Abrysvo made by Pfizer, approved 5/31/23 for adults 60 and older. Approved for pregnant women 8/21/23. Abrysvo is not an adjuvanted vaccine but it is bivalent, protecting against RSV types A and B.
Both vaccines are administered intramuscularly.
Similar side effects of headache, muscle pain, fatigue, injection site pain with both vaccines. </p>
```